# How to return icon to TextFormField's validator as string

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to trigger an error with textformfield validate.i can trigger only a text but i need to add a icon too. its working;

```
 validate: (value) {
     if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter your email address';
         } else if (isValid == false) {
           return "❗Please enter a valid email address.";
         }
```

but i need do add a svg icon. when i return svg icon and text in a row, app is crashing. how can i return a svg and text in here? thanks all

Answer (score 1):

First of all define a variable

```
bool isEmailValid =  true;
```

Now in the InputDecoreation

```
prefixIcon = isEmailValid ?? null : SvgIcon()
```

Replace SVGIcon with Some code which will render the icon

Edit:

Also in the validate function

```
validate:(v){
   if(emailIsNotValidCondition){
       setState(){isEmailValid=false}
   }

}
```

Comment: i have to add this svg icon instead of exclamation point(in the code exemple)

Comment: icon shouldnt be in text field, like prefixIcon

Comment: Replace SvgIcon with your svg icon.